# Hive, I have a QA dataset (ID, time, content, role) ordered by timestamp. How can transpose it to a format like (ID, roleA, roleB)?

Tags: python, sql, hive, user-defined-functions

[image]

I want to output a data like below:

```
    ID      roleA                           role B
    xxx     is customer service?            yes, how can i help you, how can i help you
    xxx     is customer service?            yes
    xxx     great, why this happens         wait a minute, let me check
```

I have no idea how to solve it using either sql or python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gap-and-islands problem with conditional aggregation:

```
select biz_id, send_role, min(create_time) as create_time,
       concat_ws(collect_list(content), ' ') as content
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by biz_id order by create_time) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by biz_id, send_role order by create_time) as seqnum_2,
      from t
     ) t
group by biz_id, send_role, (seqnum - seqnum_2);
```

Then with this, you can reaggregate to get what you want:

```
with x as (
      select biz_id, send_role, min(create_time) as create_time,
             concat_ws(collect_list(content), ' ') as content
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by biz_id order by create_time) as seqnum,
                   row_number() over (partition by biz_id, send_role order by create_time) as seqnum_2,
            from t
           ) t
      group by biz_id, send_role, (seqnum - seqnum_2)
     )
select biz_id,
       max(case when send_role = 2 then content end),
       max(case when send_role = 3 then content end)
from (select x.*,
             row_number() over (partition by biz_id, send_role order by create_time) as seqnum
      from x
     ) x
group by biz_id, seqnum;
```

Note:  This may puts the content on "adjacent" rows in an arbitrary order.  Getting these in the "right" order is tricky . . . in your sample data, the date/times are identical so there is no obvious ordering column.

Comment: So beautiful! I didn't realize there was so called 'gap-and-islands problem'. Thanks so much!